# Automake doesn't recognize Objective-C/C++

Tags: objective-c, objective-c++, autoconf, automake

I have configure.ac which is designed for building a shared library (both linux and macos). Now I'd like to add special demo app which uses this library and shows its features. However this demo app is only for MacOS and has .mm file in it (main.mm). I'm trying to define a target for this demo app in this way:

```
if OS_DARWIN
  EXTRA_PROGRAMS = app-demo
  app_demo_CC = OBJC
  app_demo_CXX = OBJC
  app_demo_SOURCES = demoapp/config.cc demoapp/config.h \
    demoapp/main.mm demoapp/AppDelegate.m \
    demoapp/renderer-stub.cc demoapp/renderer-stub.h \
    demoapp/view.cc demoapp/view.h
  app_demo_CPPFLAGS = ... # include directories here
  app_demo_LDFLAGS = ... # libraries and library search paths
endif
```

That's my top-level Makefile.am and as you can see, demoapp folder has all the sources for the demo app and two Objective-C files: main.mm and AppDelegate.m. 
However, when I try to run make app-demo, I'm getting this:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
```

Which means (and I confirm it from the make logs) that main.mm hasn't been compiled, neither linked.
Does anyone knows workarounds for this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is enough information to debug the problem.

I think automake supports ObjC++.  Do you get errors when invoking automake?  Does your configure.ac invoke AC_PROG_OBJCXX?  If you try compiling the files by hand, does it work?

Comment: Yep, it works and automake can find proper compiler. Please, see my answer on how I resolved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by defining separate target in Makefile.am like this:

```
.mm.o :
      $(OBJCXX) -x objective-c++ -c @DEFS@ $(CPPFLAGS) $(app_demo_CPPFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

Comment: It's quite odd that you need this.  Automake should have emitted it or something like it.  I wonder if you remove that line from the input, re-run automake, and then examine the resulting Makefile.in, if you see it.